# Generate random numbers in a specific range without duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CEILING (RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary)) *275) AS RandomNumber
```

This creates random numbers. However, it spits out duplicates

Comment: Of course, there's a 1:275 probability to get duplicates.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm wondering if there is a function that will check all rows before creating the number or some other way to go about creating 275 unique random numbers. (275 is number of rows in table)

Comment: @dnoeth actually, the probability of duplicates will be much higher.

Comment: Instead of checking a growing list of potential duplicates _every time_, why not predefine the list of values in random order? Pluck the next value off the list until you use up all 275 values. I wrote about this here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3055/generating-random-numbers-in-sql-server-without-collisions/

Comment: You need to put this in the context of whatever query or larger application you are dealing with.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I know overall probability is much higher (birthday paradox), bad wording :-)

Comment: @Dluma0092, has the answer helped you?  If not, consider editing your question to better describing what you're hoping to see.  If so, consider accepting (click the checkmark) my answer.

Comment: Voting down because of missing information in the question.  If you can please edit your question to include the details in the comment you gave to me in my first question, I'll remove my downvote.  Or, if for some reason I can't remove it, I hope someone else in the community can vote it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments to my other answer, you write:

> The table I'm working with has an ID , Name , and I want to generate a 3rd column that assigns a unique random number between 1-275 (as there are 275 rows) with no duplicates.

In the future, please include details like this in your original question.  With this information, we can help you out better.

First, let's make a sample of your problem.  We'll simplify it to just 5 rows, not 275:

```
create table #data (
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
);

insert #data values 
    (101, 'Amanda'), 
    (102, 'Beatrice'), 
    (103, 'Courtney'),
    (104, 'Denise'),
    (105, 'Elvia');
```

Let's now add the third column you want:

```
alter table #data add rando int;
```

Finally, let's update the table by creating a subquery that orders the rows randomly using `row_number()`, and applying the output the the column we just created:

```
update  reordered
set     rando = rowNum
from    (
            select      *, 
                        rowNum = row_number() over(order by newid())
            from        #data
        ) reordered;
```

Here's the result I get, but of course it will be different every time it is run:

```
select      *
from        #data

| id  | name     | rando |
+-----+----------+-------+
| 101 | Amanda   |   3   |
| 102 | Beatrice |   1   |
| 103 | Courtney |   4   |
| 104 | Denise   |   5   |
| 105 | Elvia    |   2   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a numbers table with the range of your desire.  In my case, I do it via recursive cte.  Then order the numbers table using the `newid` function.

```
with numbers as (

    select 0 as val union all
    select val + 1 from numbers where val < 275 

)

select      ord = row_number() over(order by ap.nid),
            val 
into        #rands
from        numbers n
cross apply (select nid = newid()) ap
order by    ord
option      (maxrecursion 1000);
```

One run of the code above results in a table of 276 values that begins and ends as follows:

```
| ord | val |
+-----+-----+
|  1  | 102 |
|  2  |  4  |
|  3  | 127 |
| ... | ... |
| 276 | 194 |
```

Non duplicating ordering of random numbers.

You can select from it a variety of ways, but one way could be:

```
-- initiate these to begin with 
declare @ord int = 1;
declare @val int;
declare @rand int;

-- do this on every incremental need for a random number
select  @val = val,
        @ord = @ord + 1 
from    #rands 
where   ord = @ord;

print   @val;
```

Comment: The table I'm working with has an ID , Name , and I want to generate a 3rd column that assigns a unique random number between 1-275 (as there are 275 rows) with no duplicates.                                                                                                                                        Currently I have gotten as far as :                                  
                  ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)AS INT)) % (275-1+1)+1 AS RandomNumber

Comment: Another try at it :  CEILING (RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary)) *275) AS RandomNumber